# How to have user input for the search term of a URL using cURL in C++?

Tags: php, c++, curl

I am trying to change the search term of a URL instead of having a predefined one in cURL in C++. Could anyone help me with this?

I provided some code below as to the approach I tried with no avail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace::std;

int main(void)
{

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    string searchTerm;
    cout<<"Enter ticker name: "<<endl;
    cin>>searchTerm;
    cout<<"https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="<<searchTerm<<endl;
    string whatURL = "https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+searchTerm;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, whatURL); //the error I get is in this line
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

 //int argc, const char * argv[]

    return 0;
}
```

The actual error I get is:Cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') through variadic function; call will abort at runtime

Note: I found a way online where it works by using PHP, however I do not know how to implement PHP to my C++ file (as a possible workaround).

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that libcurl is a C API, and only have C functions. Luckily you can use those directly from C++, but you can't call them with anything not available in C, like object instances for example.

Here you need to pass a string pointer, which you can get by using the [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, whatURL.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, so as I understand it for C the only option is a URL in quotes then? How would I work around this limitation seeing that it is a possibility in PHP? -- I just refreshed and saw your code, I will try that out.

Comment: @darknessReigns _'the only option is a URL in quotes then ...'_ No, you misunderstood! You are supposed to use `std::string`'s `c_str()` function when you want to pass it's contents to the C-API functions.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I defined the URL as a string then declared a new string which consists of the URL + the search term and passed that value with .c_str() in cURL's final parameter where the URL used to be.